# Excel vba how can extract only a column from a csv into spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA. How can I extract the only column from the CSV data and place it into anywhere in the spreadsheet?

I have a CSV file that looks like this that came from an API/URL

```
A,B,C,D,E
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14
14,15,16,17
```

I have this code but it displays all the CSV data. How can I get only one or two columns from the data and place it anywhere in the spreadsheet?

```
Sheets(1).Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown)).TextToColumns _
DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
Semicolon:=True, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, _
FieldInfo:= _
Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 2), Array(3, 2), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 2))
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear on specifics. What 1 column and/or 2 columns? What destination is 'anywhere in the spreadsheet'?

Comment: @Jeeped I will update the question. I want any of the columns and anywhere in the spreadsheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each of the two element array included in FieldInfo, the first element specifies the column number (1 based), and the second element specifies the data type.  To skip a column, set the second element or data type to 9.  So, for example, let's say you want to skip columns 1, 3, and 4, you'll need to set it as follows...

```
FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 9), Array(2, 2), Array(3, 9), Array(4, 9), Array(5, 2))
```

Comment: And adding the Destination:= argument can determine the destination.